# Xcode 6 importing library

Tags: ios, xcode6

I've tried drag'n'drop library [from github](https://github.com/terryworona/TWMessageBarManager) into Xcode, but whatever I do, it always gives the same problems - error: "Expetcted a type" for any iOS type - UIColor, UIFont, CGFloat... I even tried just to make header and implementation file of TWMessageBarManager and copy the code into it, but the problem stayed. Why is this happening, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you started an iOS project, not an OSX one?

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
where you using TWMessageBarManager

Comment: I'm certain that it's an iOS project because I have working app already, just wanted to import it.

Comment: ok then accept the answer as this issue happens in xcode 6. May be it will be helpful for others facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import UIKIT in TWMessageBarManager.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```